# Doesn Next.js API route cache the query result?

Tags: reactjs, api, next.js

I've got a Next.js app that uses a third party API to show some data. I'm requesting this data with Next.js API routes. Here is my `/pages/api/data.js`.

```
const handler = async (req, res) => {
    const data = await fetch('https://api.example.com/v1/data');

    res.status(200).json(data);
};

export default handler;
```

How does it work behind the scenes? Does it fetch the third party API each time I send requests to `/api/data`? Or does it cache the results at build time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does it each time you send a request. If you want to do it at build time, you have to fetch the data in the [getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation) function:

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const data = await fetch('https://api.example.com/v1/data');

  if (!data) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    }
  }

  return {
    props: { data: res.status(200).json(data) }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```